# Team work with same Firebase account

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

It's the first time I'm developing an app not by myself, but together with another guy. This app uses Firebase backend and we both need access to realtime database to modify nodes related to those parts which we're developing.

Is there a way to provide access to a single Firebase project to different users without me sharing my Google account credentials? Something like collaborators on GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions is actually used for this.

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and select the specific project.
2. Click on Settings (Cog button beside Overview) and select Permissions. This will redirect you to the Google Cloud Console, IAM & Admin part.

   [image]
3. Click on ADD. Under *Members*, type in the Gmail of the other user, and in *Roles*, select `Project > Editor`.

   [image]

   [image]
4. Click on ADD.

From there, the corresponding Firebase Project should be visible on the other user's Firebase Console in a few hours. (However, if you're in a hurry, you could just copy-paste the link of the project with the other user logged-in on Google and they would still be able to access it).

From there, they'd be able to edit out the Database part or whichever you needed.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking.

Comment: You're welcome. I added in some screenshots just in case. Cheers! :)